# code after [NSThread cancel] is not invoked

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, nsthread

I have a instance variable of type `NSThread`:

```
NSThread *workerThread;
```

In one function, I instantiate this `NSThread` variable & starts it:

```
-(void)startTask {
  workerThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                    selector:@selector(doWork)
                                                      object:nil];
  [workerThread start];
}
```

(The `doWork` is doing long running task.)

In another function, I try to s**top the task & stop/kill the worker thread & do something else**:

```
-(void) stopTask {
 // stop long running task
 [self stopWork]
 NSLog(@"I can see this log");
 [workerThread cancel];

 // code never reach here
 [self doSomethingElse];
}
```

The problem I encounter is after I started the worker thread, when I call `stopTask`, the `[self doSomethingElse]` never get invoked.

Why? How to get rid of this problem?

Comment: On which thread are you calling `stopTask`? It seems like you're invoking it on the `workerThread`. Then it's no wonder that the line isn't reached...

Comment: @Gero, I am not calling stopTask on workerThread, I am calling it in the same thread where I call startTask.

Comment: That's very weird indeed. Can you provide a demo project somewhere (github?) that illustrates the issue?